# Control turtlesim via webpage

Tags: ros, rosbridge, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was trying to control turtlesim from a webpage in my android phone. I followed this tutorial:
http://iguanatronics.com/simple-tutorial-on-rosbridge-and-roslibjs/

I ran "roslaunch rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket.launch" and "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node" in my laptop. Also i opened the web page to control the turtlesim in my android mobile. But, the web page displays:

"Error connecting to websocket server.
Connection to websocket server closed."

Please help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250958/control-turtlesim-via-webpage/) by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2016-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I found the solution by myself. The IP address to be specified is that of the ros machine, and not the non ros one. So, i simply put the ip address in this line:

```
url : 'ws://192.168.0.100:9090'
```

And i could control theturtlesim from non ros computer.

Thanks !

---

Originally posted by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) with karma: 125 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0